# What's a good platform to create your own personal wiki?

Tags: database, note-taking, cloud-service, wiki

I have a lot of notes (all on Google Drive right now) and would like to one day organize them into my own personal wikipedia.  While being on Google's cloud is nice (I can quickly search key words), it's still a hassle to transition from one topic to another.  For example, if I am reading through my notes and a term or concept pops up and I forgot what it is, it would take a while for me to find the exact document and section where I explained it before.  It would be nice if such a platform can solve that issue either by:

- Either allow me to quickly generate a link to the concept (like on wiki where you can click on link for a term/concept)
- If no link, a roll over pop up or something would be nice as well, or some other way that gets me to the relevant information

Also, would be nice if this wiki is accessible on the internet like my Google drive is accessible.  Finally, since my notes reflect hundreds of hours of work, I need to trust whoever is hosting my notes.  I tend to trust Google with not losing my files.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any research on your own, and rejected anything that you've found? If so, you should let us know what you've looked at and why it was inadequate. If not, you should do some research on your own.

Comment: You can read this article [How to make you own Wiki from Wikipedia using Python](https://jwork.org/home/node/69) that uses MediaWiki as a backend

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at [Wiki matrix - the Wiki Comparison Site](https://www.wikimatrix.org/).

Use their [choice wizard](https://www.wikimatrix.org/wizard) which will ask you series of questions.

At each stage it tells you how many wikis match your criteria, and at the end you can choose some to compare.

[image]

[image]
image snipped, but there is a lot of detail.

Many years ago, I hit on DokuWiki and have using it ever since. I wish that I could tell you why I chose it, but I have forgotten. I will say that I have never found anything that I wanted it to do that it could not. It has 1.1k questions on Stack Exchange, and a bunch of great plug-ins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), we're run it "internally" on a local network and "externally" on a web-accessible server (shared hosting etc.)  which means we can log in from anywhere and read / edit.

It's not perfect, but it does all the basics very well and reliably (I've been using it for over a decade and it's never failed) and since it keeps all the data as standard text files it's easy to backup / restore your data with no complicated steps.

It can run happily from a very basic server such as a Raspberry Pi and a lot of web hosting companies have auto-installers for it.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend OneNote. It has a bit of a learning curve and occasional hiccup but it has improved significantly.

I could not find any better solutions for my needs. I can printout pdfs in my notes, drag and drop pictures, file and etc. Also, I can review my notes on my 13 inch iPad and take notes with my iPad pen.

It is free and cross-platform. for my storage, I purchased the office 365 as I get all MS Products (Word, Excel) as well as 1TB of Storage.

Answer (score 0):

https://obsidian.md/

and

https://logseq.com/

both are really good and locally run. you can store the main folder/vault on a server and then access and edit from any device.

Comment: You can improve your answer by supplying some details on both.